# The derivative of a scalar function should be linear implies that it cannot contain a term of the form $x^2, y^3 ...$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 44-45, he argues that

[image]
[image]

But this means that the derivative of any scalar function cannot contain a term such as $x^2$, $y^3$... because it does not make the derivative linear, but this is clearly wrong, so what am I misinterpreting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about differentiable functions $g$ from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$, $g'(x)$ is a number. But when $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, $g'(p)$ is a linear map, not a number. In fact, if $g$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ and if $a=g'(x)$, we can see this number as a linear map: the multiplication by $a$. That's the connections between these to notions of derivative.

So, if $g(x)=x^3$, $g'(x)=3x^2$. That's not a problem: $g'(a)$ is the linear map $x\mapsto 3a^2x$.The presence of that square doesn't prevent this map from being linear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Santos. Then is it correct to interpret Munkres argument as: If $f$ was differentiable, the derivative would be a matrix, and when we multiply that matrix with $\vec u$, we shouldn't have gotten any term with such as $h^2$ or $1 / k$ (which is the case in this particular example) because when $\vec u = \vec a + \vec b$ we couldn't have $B * u = B * a + B*b$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas That's it, except that I wouldn't say that the derivative is a matrix; it's a linear map.

Comment: Definitely, but from what I have seen so far, any linear map can be represented as a matrix.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Indeed.